# Why not using high frequency AC at homes?

Tags: ac, high-frequency

I am a student at school but I learn electronics in parallel as I love it, all my knowledge came from the internet, so if there is a problem in my question please fix it.I came across something called "conductor's skin effect" which states that the higher AC frequency the less it harms the human body as electrons move on the outside on the skin and not the inside.

Why the mains voltage in homes are clocked at 50 or 60 Hz which are deadly, rather than in kHz? If my knowledge is correct it's less deadly.

Is the problem is because all devices won't work, and it will take ton of time to change the frequency worldwide or the problem is due to some electrical characteristics like power loss or EMI or what?

In short why 50 or 60 Hz is used in homes rather than frequencies in kHz?

Comment: Hint: how would you create that kHz mains voltage? What creates the mains frequency today? What would need to be done to change that (from 50/60 Hz to kHz)? What would the change from 50/60 Hz to kHz range mean for the distribution network (think about transformers)? Is the reason (skin effect) why you would want mains power in kHz enough to compensate for all disadvantages? Does a few kHz give enough skin effect to notice a difference from 50/60 Hz?

Comment: What's the link between skin effect and the human body?

Comment: The relationship of **skin effect** to **safety** is mis-placed...it is current that is dangerous, not frequency.

Comment: @glen_geek while you're right that current kills, frequency also matters. DC is significantly safer and higher frequencies have less ability to force muscle contractions. Much of the problem with 60hz is it causes muscle contractions so the person receives a sustained hit of current because they can't let go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because interference is a problem anyway, having a higher transmission frequency makes the problem worse. Magnetic coupling is proportional to the rate of change of magnetic flux hence, eddy current induction into conducting objects increases proportionately with frequency. The formula for induced EMF and flux is: -

$$V = N\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}$$

Where N, for a single wire transmission is 1.

Electric coupling is via capacitance to ground and, given that a capacitor decreases its impedance with frequency, this also becomes a greater problem. This is under-pinned in this equation: -

$$I = C\dfrac{dv}{dt}$$

If a higher frequency is chosen \$\dfrac{dv}{dt}\$ increases proportionately.

So EMI issues generally rise linearly with transmission frequency.

Another big problem is the efficiency of power transfer because, the decreased capacitive reactance causes higher reactive currents to ground and, this causes an added power loss in the cable giving rise to potentially some serious overheating of that cable. Lower frequencies are more efficient in power transfer. This is seen today in DC-to-DC links.

Also, skin effect makes the effective conductor cross sectional area smaller and, in turn, this means more cable resistance and higher transmission losses.

Answer (score 3):

It would be pretty difficult to make AC motors, whose speed is dependent on frequency, turn at reasonable speed. They would need many, many more poles.

2-pole motors already run at 3600RPM at 60Hz. If your supply was just 1000Hz, even an 8-pole motor would spin at 15,000RPM, and your question is asking about multiple KHz.

That's probably the whole reason 50/60Hz was chosen: It was most practical to  make generators (basically just reverse motors) that turned at those speeds.